# MySQL Query (with subquery) optimization

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

I'm having trouble figuring how to speed up the query below.

```
SELECT 
(SELECT SUM(pi2.OperationMW) FROM projectsimport pi2 
    WHERE pi2.CommissionYear  <=  pi.CommissionYear 
    AND pi2.TurbineOEM = pi.TurbineOEM 
    AND pi2.Country = 'US' )  as y,
    TurbineOEM as Name , CommissionYear  
FROM projectsimport pi 
WHERE TurbineOEM != '' AND Country = 'US' 
AND CommissionYear > 1993 
AND CommissionYear <= 2018 
AND CommissionYear IS NOT NULL    
GROUP BY TurbineOEM, CommissionYear 
Order by TurbineOEM, CommissionYear
```

Running explain gives me the following results:

[explain results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DE1L.jpg)

I feel like I'm missing something pretty obvious but any help would be appreciated

Comment: You didn't provide any clues on how it is considered to be slow. I'm not an expert on this field but it seems a single index on `CommissionYear` could help a lot.

Comment: I have an INDEX on CommissionYear but MySQL chooses to use the CountryIndex as the KEY in the execution plan. I tried removing the CountryIndex in an attempt to get the optimizer to use the CommisionYearIndex but the optimizer then leaves the KEY as null and the number of rows in the primary query jumps to 32374 (from 5703). Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'how the query is considered slow'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Composite indexes for `projectsimport`:

```
INDEX(Country, TurbineOEM, CommissionYear, OperationMW)
INDEX(Country, CommissionYear, TurbineOEM)
```

Comment: This worked, query time went from ~15 seconds to a fraction of a second. Thank you.

Comment: @Kai -Good!  How to create optimal composite indexes: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql